# Checking other domains SSL certificates using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https

I need to check if a given domain has a valid SSL certificate using NodeJS, so I'm using the `https` module like so:

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  host: 'www.some-site.com',
  method: 'get',
  path: '/'
};

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log('Certificate Status: ', res.socket.authorized);
});

req.on('error', error => {
  console.error('Error: ', error);
});

req.end();
```

I've been testing this against some of the sites listed as being insecure in Google's transparency report: https://transparencyreport.google.com/https/top-sites

Some of the results:

- `aliexpress.com` - `Certificate Status: true` Correct
- `expired.badssl.com` - `Certificate Status: false` Correct

Both correct. However, when a site does not use SSL at all the value for `socket.authorized` is still true:

- `alibaba.com` - `Certificate Status: true` Wrong
- `www.bbc.com` - `Certificate Status: true` Wrong

What is the correct way to validate whether a domain has a valid SSL certificate?

Comment: The domains alibaba.com and bbc.com have vaild ssl certificate associated with them, click here to check.. https://alibaba.com, you can verify ssl certificate status here..............https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Comment: As Nithin pointed out the certificates are correct. The two sites you pointed out perform an automatic redirection from HTTPS to HTTP when opened in a web browser. Therefore I assume you thought that they don't support SSL.

Comment: You guys were right, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments for my question, these sites happened to be using redirects from `https` to `http` as soon as the sites loaded. So the initial 'valid cert' results were correct.

To get around this I used an npm package zfollow-redirects`, and this solved the issue.

From the package description:

> Drop-in replacement for Nodes http and https that automatically
>   follows redirects.